# How do I get a detailed backlog report from TFS2012 Scrum 2.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

My team is using the Scrum 2.0 template in TFS 2012.  We've entered detailed user stories as items in the product backlog.  How do I get them output in a format suitable for sharing with business stakeholders?

There is a "Backlog Overview" report, but it has only the list of item titles with hours remaining.  I need a report that includes all of the detail that we added to each product backlog item, including Description, Acceptance Criteria, State, Priority, AssignedTo, etc...

Surely this exists already?  Or did the TFS team completely overlook any need to communicate detail to external stakeholders and auditors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visual Studio ALM Rangers released a tool called the [Team Foundation Server Word Add-in](http://vsarword4tfs.codeplex.com/)a couple weeks back to

> import work items from a Team Foundation Server Team Project and generate professional-looking Word document from TFS Work items.

It's fairly early days for this particular tool, but check out the readme in the downloads section.

[Team For Word](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eranruso/archive/2010/12/28/team-for-word-a-tfs-word-client-and-a-user-guide-for-it.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+EranRuso+%28Eran+Ruso%29&utm_content=Google+Reader) is another very similar tool made by a 3rd party, i believe it was originally made for TFS2008 but has been updated to work with 2010 and probably works with 2012 if you install the team explorer for 2010

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  The Scrum templates included don't match the Scrum 2.0 fields, but I can easily tweak them with the included Layout Designer.  Thanks!